# Is there a workaround to my attempted Hive insert

Tags: hive, insert, hiveql, hive-partitions

I copy the structure of schema2.card_master over to schema1.card_master using

`hive> create table schema1.card_master like schema2.card_master;`

That works, and it is partitioned as was the original on a field.   This new table has hundreds of fields so they are inconvenient to list out, but I want all the fields populated from the original table using a Join filter.   Now I want to populate it using a JOIN:

`hive> insert overwrite table schema1.card_master   (select * from schema2.card_master ccm INNER JOIN schema1.accounts da on ccm.cm13 = da.cm13);`

`FAILED: SemanticException 1:23 Need to specify partition columns because the destination table is partitioned. Error encountered near token 'cmdl_card_master'`

I checked the partition that was copied over, and it was a field mkt_cd that could take on 2 values, US or PR.

So I try

```
hive> insert overwrite table schema1.card_master PARTITION (mkt_cd='US')  (select * from schema2.card_master ccm INNER JOIN schema1.accounts da on ccm.cm13 = da.cm13);
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10044]: Line 1:23 Cannot insert into target table because column number/types are different ''US'': Table insclause-0 has 255 columns, but query has 257 columns.
hive>
```

What is going on here?  Is there any work around to load my data without having to explicitly mention all the fields in the Select statement for schema2.card_master ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select *` selects columns from each table in a join. Use `select ccm.*` instead of `select *` to select columns from `ccm` table only. Also remove static partition specification ('US'), use dynamic instead, because `ccm.*` contains partition column, and when you are loading static partition you should not have partition column in the select.

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

insert overwrite table schema1.card_master partition(mkt_cd) --dynamic partition
select ccm.* --use alias 
  from schema2.card_master ccm 
       INNER JOIN schema1.accounts da on ccm.cm13 = da.cm13
;
```

Comment: I ran across a situation where a table had 2 partition columns.  I did ```partition(col1,col2)``` with everything else in the above answer staying the same but the Hive query did not run (it did not return a syntax error either.)

Comment: @MarkGinsburg Please ask one more question and provide more details what is happening: what is in the job tracker logs, more details about input files number and format, cluster capacity

Comment: My 2-partition table turned out to be mammoth and it exceeded the resources... had to configure the JVM with more memory for the Map stage.  So that wasn't an issue with the query itself.